How to Spill Range to grow with Master Spill Range with Excel?
I am trying to setup a series of dynamic arrays. Unfortunately for one of the stages, I need a spill range to create another spill range, and adjust its spacing accordingly.
Please note, Range B3:B96 is entirely composed of merged cells. Currently these are manually entered to replicate range H3#. The range(s) in Column C (through Column F) are individual spill ranges, filtered based on product in corresponding cell in Column B. In a true dynamic situation, the number of rows of each instance in Column B would need to grow, depending on the size of the Dynamic array in Column C.
I'm having difficulty formatting the sheet to view the component information in Column C (4-collums x n-rows), relevant to each product listed in H3# (currently manually replicated in Column B) without spilling into the next item.
I tried to #spill the dynamic array from H3# into Column B, but doesn't seem to work as cells are merged (to create required rows for subsequent spill operation in Column C (4-collums x n-rows).
If I try and use the formula from Column C to reference the H3# array directly, each item spills into each other.
I'm looking solution that replicates the 'Product' in Column B or leaves blank cells the size of each secondary spill rage (Column C). Or any other bright spark ideas.


Another approach is required to get what you want. I can see at list two options for your choice:

Use a pivot table. The "B:F" table looks very similar to a table which can get by pivoting.
Use Power Query to query your data and get the result.

Both these options dynamically use worksheet's space to put the report.
